# Server Time doesn't match with browser time on server

Tags: timezone, windows-server-2008

I have a application server (Windows 2008 R2 64 Bit) with third party hosting service provider 
 They say my server location is California

When I Remote-In to my server, my server Timezone is set to Central Time.

If I open google on my server and search for "current time" it says Washington DC and gives Eastern Time.

1. How can I exactly figure out where is my server physically located?
2. Can this be possible server machine time and Server browser time be different?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a general idea by doing a lookup/GeoLocation by IP. Try this: http://www.maxmind.com/. Logon to your server and get it's IP address. Not the local one, try getting it's outward facing IP by going to whatismyip.com and use Maxmind to get a general idea of it's location.

Comment: It gives Latitude and Longitude but not address (city/State). using Latitude and longitude it found (http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com) location as 120th St, Potwin, KS 67123. Still can not understand why my server browser is showing Eastern time.